# How do I make an interactive backwards progress bar that works with a timer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, timer

Is there any way that I could be able to make a progress bar go backwards? I have seen an example that told me to turn the progress bar 180 degrees, but that seems like a very dirty way to do it. What I'm looking for is so the progress bar can be time controlled, and so that a by pressing a button, I would add three seconds to the timer, thus pulling back the bar a bit (Say the timer is at 7 seconds, pressing the button would add a second, bringing it to 8 seconds thus pulling back the timer a little bit). If I could incorporate this with a countdown timer as well, it would be cool, but not 100% needed. Here is what I have so far. Changes that need to be made is so that the timer goes backwards instead of forwards, and so I could be able to add time on to it by pressing a button.

HTML:

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var interval = 2, //How much to increase the progressbar per frame
    updatesPerSecond = 1000/60, //Set the nr of updates per second (fps)
    progress =  $('progress'),
    animator = function(){
        progress.val(progress.val()+interval);
        $('#val').text(progress.val());
        if ( progress.val()+interval < progress.attr('max')){
           setTimeout(animator, updatesPerSecond);
        } else { 
            $('#val').text('Done');
            progress.val(progress.attr('max'));
        }
    }

setTimeout(animator, updatesPerSecond);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/526hM/1161/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st: - We will create a new function for `reverse`

2nd: - Add `min="0"` attribute to the progress bar

3rd: - change progress value to 200 `progress.val('200');` before running the `setTimeout()`

Finally: - change `+` to `-` on `progress.val() - interval`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var interval = 2, //How much to increase the progressbar per frame
        updatesPerSecond = 1000/60, //Set the nr of updates per second (fps)
        progress =  $('progress'),
        animator = function(){
            progress.val(progress.val()+interval);
            $('#val').text(progress.val());
            if ( progress.val()+interval < progress.attr('max')){
               setTimeout(animator, updatesPerSecond);
            } else { 
                $('#val').text('Done');
                progress.val(progress.attr('max'));
            }
        },
        reverse = function(){
         progress.val(progress.val() - interval);
            $('#val').text(progress.val());
            if ( progress.val() - interval > progress.attr('min')){
               setTimeout(reverse, updatesPerSecond);
            } else { 
                $('#val').text('Done');
                progress.val(progress.attr('min'));
            }
        }
    progress.val('200');
    setTimeout(reverse, updatesPerSecond);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<progress max="200" min="0" value="1"></progress>
<div id="val"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply start with `progress.val` at its maximum, and decrement it.  When it gets to 0, you're done.